# Relationship between sampajanna definitions in SN 47.2 and SN 47.35

Tags: pali-canon, sampajana

What is the relationship between the definitions of *sampajañña* (clear comprehension) in SN 47.2 and SN 47.35?

From [SN 47.35](https://suttacentral.net/sn47.35/en/bodhi) (translated by Bodhi):

> “And how, bhikkhus, does a bhikkhu exercise clear comprehension? Here,
>   bhikkhus, for a bhikkhu feelings are understood as they arise,
>   understood as they remain present, understood as they pass away.
>   Thoughts are understood as they arise, understood as they remain
>   present, understood as they pass away. Perceptions are understood as
>   they arise, understood as they remain present, understood as they pass
>   away. It is in this way, bhikkhus, that a bhikkhu exercises clear
>   comprehension.

From [SN 47.2](https://suttacentral.net/sn47.2/en/bodhi) (translated by Bodhi):

> “And how, bhikkhus, does a bhikkhu exercise clear comprehension? Here,
>   bhikkhus, a bhikkhu is one who acts with clear comprehension when
>   going forward and returning; when looking ahead and looking aside;
>   when drawing in and extending the limbs; when wearing his robes and
>   carrying his outer robe and bowl; when eating, drinking, chewing his
>   food, and tasting; when defecating and urinating; when walking,
>   standing, sitting, falling asleep, waking up, speaking, and keeping
>   silent. It is in such a way that a bhikkhu exercises clear
>   comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *And how, bhikkhus, does a bhikkhu exercise clear comprehension? Here, bhikkhus, for a bhikkhu feelings are understood as they arise,
>   understood as they remain present, understood as they pass away.
>   Thoughts are understood as they arise, understood as they remain
>   present, understood as they pass away. Perceptions are understood as
>   they arise, understood as they remain present, understood as they pass
>   away. It is in this way, bhikkhus, that a bhikkhu exercises clear
>   comprehension.*
>
> *SN 47.35*

The above means feelings, perceptions & thoughts are clearly understood in terms of the Dhamma, namely, they are impermanent, not-self, not to be clung to.

Note: This is not vipassana, namely, observing arising & passing of feelings, perceptions & thoughts. It is understanding feelings, perceptions & thoughts, including when they are purposefully used. Thus, when speaking to another, for example, the mind understands: "*These thoughts are conventions, subjective, not to be clung to, etc*".

> *And how, bhikkhus, does a bhikkhu exercise clear comprehension? Here, bhikkhus, a bhikkhu is one who acts with clear comprehension when
>   going forward and returning; when looking ahead and looking aside;
>   when drawing in and extending the limbs; when wearing his robes and
>   carrying his outer robe and bowl; when eating, drinking, chewing his
>   food, and tasting; when defecating and urinating; when walking,
>   standing, sitting, falling asleep, waking up, speaking, and keeping
>   silent. It is in such a way that a bhikkhu exercises clear
>   comprehension.*
>
> *SN 47.2*

The above is exactly the same. When walking, the monk has clear-comprehension, such as: "*I am monk; I must walk so I make a good public impression*" or "*I am a monk; I must eat non-hurriedly; so I make a good public impression*"; or the monk reflects: "*This walking is not self*" (such as when Rahula was walking behind the Buddha in MN 62 and the Buddha rebuked Rahula for regarding the Buddha as a "self" or with "beauty").

Answer (score 2):

In line with what I said in my other answer, both are descriptions of self-awareness, of not getting carried away by the circumstances.

This does not refer to "zombie bare awareness" executed mechanically, but to normal, pragmatic, careful self-awareness of an intelligent person.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, a lot of modern mindfulness teachers seem to be teaching it wrongly. They teach "*Be aware in the present moment and simply observe X without judging*" when it should be "*Don't forget to keep observing X and thoroughly understanding the arising, changing and ceasing of X without judging*", where X refers to body, feelings, thoughts and phenomena, and "without judging" means actively removing greed and aversion.

Comment: Yup. Not just arising/ceasing and removing greed/aversion, but also seeing any biases, attachments, egoistic motives, defensiveness, self-promotion etc.

Comment: I'll group "biases, attachments, egoistic motives, defensiveness, self-promotion" under views. So, removing greed, aversion and views.

Answer (score -1):

The difference is, in the 4 jhanas,  SN 47.35  is the more suitable range of activity, since one is typically doing quiet sitting with eyes closed. SN 47.35 is the same as a portion AN 4.41, which clearly puts it in the 4 jhanas and samadhi development context. Standard 3rd jhana formula, explicitly states one has sati and sampajano.

Outside of 4 jhanas, S&S sati and sampajano do not shut off, they continue working, but with a dyanmic range of activity as SN 47.2 gives examples for.

sampajano  in both SN 47.35 and SN 47.2 mean the same thing, sampajano is one who is lucidly-discerning, or clearly-comprehending exactly what they're doing every moment.